# CloudFlare issues when new version of service deployed to environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloudflare, java-11

i have a very weird issue, i had to update the java service from java 8 to 11 and spring boot from 2.2… to 2.7.18, the project run very well locally and also run well using postman with any environment, however when it gets deployed to the dev or other environments cloudflare blocks the requests returns 403 and after like 24 hrs it works. What could be the issue cuz it cant go in the prod, customers will not wait for 24 hrs to connect to the service. But from postman no issues at all.

So there are four cookies that if deleted everything works but as soon as they get added again it doesnt work, those cookies are important and cant be adjusted, and it was working with java 8 previously, cookies are not generated but this service they get added when navigating to the main organisation page. I tried lots of things such as spring security configuration, i even removed completely the security configurations and it was still not working. Then i deployed the previos version that was fully working in dev and now even the working version is not working, so thats not the environment, not spring configurations, only cloud flare is left so why it would block the requests ? All this started when deployed the version to dev from there cloud flare makes issues. Is there anything in java 11 that is worth having a closer look ?